# JQuery Galleria alignment in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, alignment, galleria

I have added JQUERY Galleria a site that I have created but am having problems with the alignment in firefox.

Chrome renders the galleria fine, but in Firefox the actual galleria displays to the right of the div that i want it in.

See http://www.vimisolanki.com/index.php/home/professional as an example of what I mean.

I've tried looking at the styling using FireBug within Firefox but I cant seem to figure out what the issue is.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#galleria` container is not clearing properly the floated divs above it, your title `span5` div in this case, so just clear it properly and it works.

```
#galleria {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: That's hard to tell going per his site css.

Comment: @boot-baby-boot the galleria container is being placed exactly next to the title div because it is not properly cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `float:left;` and maybe having full width in the images?.That way,you can easily tell what's not working.